# Travis-CI + (BrowserStack or other browser providers)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci, browserstack

Has anyone tried to connect [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) browsers to [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) vms?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? BrowserStack.com provides selenium support. You can also have a look at [Browserstack Runner](https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-runner) which can be used to run tests on commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.browserstack.com/automate/continuous-integration? They seem to support Jenkins, Travis and Circle.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried BrowserStack on Travis CI or otherwise, but it looks like it should work if you're using Selenium.

Another option would be [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/opensource/travis), who also provide browsers for Selenium tests.